# How to prove $X\subseteq Z,Y\subseteq Z,Z\setminus X\subseteq Y$ implies $ Z\subseteq X\cup Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have no idea to prove 
$$
X\subseteq Z,Y\subseteq Z,Z\setminus X\subseteq Y\text{, then } Z\subseteq X\cup Y 
$$

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: In fact, $Z = X \cup Y$

Answer (score 3):

Take $x\in Z$. If $x\in X$, then $x\in X\cup Y$. If $x\notin X$, then $x \in Z \setminus X$, and since $Z \setminus X \subseteq Y$, we have $x\in Y$, which means $x\in X\cup Y$. Then, we conclude $Z \subseteq X\cup Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $ x \in Z$ and $ x \notin X$ so that $ x \in Z \setminus X$.

By hypothesis, $Z \setminus X \subset Y$, so $x \in Y$.

Answer (score 0):

$Z\setminus X\subseteq Y \iff z\in Z\wedge z\not\in X \rightarrow z\in Y$

So $z\in Z\iff (z\in Z \wedge z\in X) \vee (z\in Z \vee z\not\in x)  \implies z\in X \vee z \in Y\iff z\in X\cup Y$